# Need help to understand matrix used in Kernel Class for ConvolveOp

Tags: java, swing, graphics2d

This is the code from filthy rich clients--by Chet Hasse.

```
 private void buildConvolveOpTab(JTabbedPane tabbedPane) {
    BufferedImage dstImage = null;
    float[] sharpen = new float[] {
         0.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f,
        -1.0f,  5.0f, -1.0f,
         0.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f
    };
    Kernel kernel = new Kernel(3, 3, sharpen);
    ConvolveOp op = new ConvolveOp(kernel);
    dstImage = op.filter(sourceImage, null);

    tabbedPane.add("Convolve", new JLabel(new ImageIcon(dstImage)));
}
```

Can anyone please tell me how to decide the elements of that matrix "sharpen".
I have googled it a lot but didn't find anything useful.
Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just one of the discrete convolution kernel, mostly used in image processing to apply various spatial filters like `blur` or `sharpen` or `edge detection`. The particular kernel that you have mentioned is approximation of `laplacian` sharpen filter.

1. Reference: http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/HIPR2/log.htm
2. Convolution Filter Applet: http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/HIPR2/convolutiondemo.htm